# Geting my Tech Licence again

Tags: united-states, license

Back in the 90's I received my Tech license. I let it expire. Now many years later and I have the time (Retired) I would like to get back into Ham Radio. Do I need to take the Tech exam again? Or If I show proof that I took the test and received a tech license I can just pay any fees and be reissued a tech license?

Answer (score 4):

**You must retake the examination.** The relevant regulation is [§97.505](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c89c6646e415ced62cde7df69e8f017a&mc=true&node=se47.5.97_1505&rgn=div8). Unfortunately it is formatted in a table which I can't quote in full neatly, but the relevant part says:

> (a) The administering VEs must give credit as specified below to an
>   examinee holding any of the following license grants:
>
> …
>       (3) Technician Plus; or Technician granted on or after March 21, 1987
>           Expired and beyond the renewal
>   grace period
>                   No credit.
>       …
>
> (b) The administering VEs must give credit
>   to an examinee holding a CSCE for each element the CSCE indicates the
>   examinee passed within the previous 365 days.

On the other hand, if you had held a higher class of license, you would be able to regain your license at that class by only taking the Technician exam.

Note that in any case **you will also be assigned a new call sign.** If you want your old call sign and it is still available, then you may apply for it as a vanity call sign; this can only be done *after* you have your new call sign.

---

Look at it this way: you have time, and you need to take the exam. You might as well shoot for Extra along the way! Get studying!